# Different conditions in one select statement

Tags: sql-server-2008, select, where-clause

How can you `Select` two columns and have each column test for it's own condition and not the other's ?

Let's say I have a select that `Count` every records in a table. In one column I want every records from this week, and in the second one I want all record since the beginning of the year.

I have two conditions but they each apply to a specific column :

```
        WHERE date BETWEEN @Monday AND @SUNDAY  /* Weekly */
        WHERE date >= @JanuaryFirst             /* Annual */
```

But can't just put it like this because I will only get this week's record in both columns. I thought I could use an `IF`condition but I don't think I can simply say "If you are column A test for this, if not test for the second one".

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use INNER SELECTS, like this:

```
select vehicule,
       (select count(*) from tablename t1 where t1.vehicule = t.vehicule and date BETWEEN @Monday AND @SUNDAY) as 'Weekly',
       (select count(*) from tablename t1 where t1.vehicule = t.vehicule and date >= @JanuaryFirst) as 'Annual'
from tablename t
```

Comment: And what would be the best solution ? Kinda new to SQL:P

Comment: This is rather expensive, no? Also I recommend against using `'single quotes'` for alias delimiters; this syntax has been deprecated. Much safer to use `[square brackets]` or `"double quotes"`, and only if necessary.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Why is it safer to use brackets or double quotes ?

Comment: Because `'this syntax'` for column aliases has been deprecated. This means that at some point the code will stop working. I [talk about this here](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases) but [official docs are here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/ms143729(v=sql.100)).

Answer (score 4):

Here is a version that doesn't yield multiple scans:

```
select vehicule,
  weekly = SUM(CASE WHEN date BETWEEN @Monday AND @SUNDAY THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
  annual = SUM(CASE WHEN date >= @JanuaryFirst THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
from dbo.tablename AS t
GROUP BY vehicule;
```

Or you could also try the slightly less verbose:

```
select vehicule,
  weekly = COUNT(CASE WHEN date BETWEEN @Monday AND @SUNDAY THEN 1 END),
  annual = COUNT(CASE WHEN date >= @JanuaryFirst THEN 1 END)
from dbo.tablename AS t
GROUP BY vehicule;
```

Comment: Thanks i'll try this approach because my request is really long so when I add subquery it takes like 4 minutes to execute.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid subqueries you can use:

```
select vehicule,
sum(case when date BETWEEN @Monday AND @SUNDAY then 1 else 0 end)  as 'Weekly',
sum(case when date >= @JanuaryFirst then 1 else 0 end)  as 'Annual' 
group by vehicule
```